# Geodesic complete subset of a connected manifold

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry

This may be a very silly question but let us consider a connected Riemanian manifold $(M,g)$ and a subset $O\subset M$. Can we have $O$ geodesic complete (in the sense of all geodesics linking two points in $O$ can be extended and still remains in $O$) without $O=M$ ?

Can we have $dim(O)=dim(M)$ with $O\subsetneq M$ ?

Comment: What about an open convex subset of (say) the plane?

Comment: What if $O$ is the image of a geodesic?

Comment: @hardmath For me an open convex subset $O$ of the plane $P$ embedded with a simple Euclidean metric is geodesic convex but not complete since for $x,y\in O$, $\gamma(t)=t*x+(1-t)*y$ will escape from $O$. It could be the case with some specific metric but could become unconnected in this case ?

Comment: I wasn't clear what you meant by "can be extended" (certainly any line segment in an open set can be extended by epsilon without escaping).

Comment: @DanielRust Yes of course ! I must be tired and missing the most obvious thing. The set of geodesics works in this case. I guess we can find other examples by this idea of getting stuck to a dimension (like any plane $P$ in $\mathbf{R}^3$). This question was really silly actually :)

Comment: The question is more interesting if you want the subset $O$ to have the same dimension as $M$. You might like to change your question? (I must admit though, I don't know of an example off the top of my head in this case).

Comment: @DanielRust I have updated the question to reflect this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in the comments, totally geodesic submanifolds give examples with $\dim O < \dim M$. If you want $O$ to have full dimension then the only examples are (unions of) the connected components of M:

Let $M$ be a complete connected manifold and $O$ be a complete open subset. If $x\in O$ then for any point $p \in M$, let $\gamma:[0,1]\to M$ be the minimising geodesic joining $x$ to $p$  (guaranteed by Hopf-Rinow). Since $O$ is open, there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that the restriction of $\gamma$ to $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ is a geodesic in $O$. Therefore the full extension $\gamma$ (and in particular $p$) must lie in $O$ by the completeness of $O$.